# Update function for typeahead

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I want to get data from server and suggest with typeahead.
I get my data from list to an usl like `/foo/q=QUERY` and this query return json like `["salam","bye", "khodafez,]`.
How i can use from bootstrap typeahead to suggestion.
I try this code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#vahid").typeahead({
                     // ???    
                });
            });
          </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead), you just provide a function for `source` in the options:

```
$("#vahid").typeahead({
    source: function(query, process) {
        // `query` is the text in the field
        // `process` is a function to call back with the array
        $.ajax({
            // Your URL
            url: "/foo",

            // Your argument with the query as its value
            data: {q: query},

            // Success callback -- since it expects the first
            // parameter to be the data, and that's what the
            // success callback is called with, you can just
            // use `process` directly
            success: process
        });
    }
});
```

The above assumes that the response correctly identifies the response as `Content-Type: application/json`. If it doesn't, add

```
dataType: "json"
```

...to your `ajax` options.

I'm using the asynchronous mechanism because you're querying a server. If you already had the data client-side, you could simply return it from the `source` function directly. But they (intelligently) don't require you to retrieve it synchronously from the server, as that would lead to a bad XU.

Answer (score 1):

Accourding to docs https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead
you can add ajax attr like :

```
$('#myElement').typeahead({
    ajax: '/path/to/mySource'
});
```

or

```
var mySource = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Terry'}, { id: 2, name: 'Mark'}, { id: 3, name: 'Jacob'}
];

$('#myElement').typeahead({
    source: mySource
});
```

for local data